# How to add random url to a href inside a for loop in php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a scenario :

There are some divs are displaying the based on the following loop:

```
  <?php foreach($posts->content as $entry) { ?>
   <div><a class="popup-with-zoom-anim wiplay" id="<?=$entry->id?>"
   href="#small-dialog" data-detail-id ="<?=$entry->id?>"
   data-stream="******">content here</a></div>
   <?php } ?>
```

In the a href "data-stream"  i want to pass some youtube url so the each div will show random url based on th for loop.
I have the following code tried.But not working.How will  we call this function inside the loop?

```
$assoc_array = array( "url" => "https://www.youtube.com
/watch?v=A7XdOyZIkko", 
        "url" => "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMH0bHeiRNg

  ", 
        "url" => "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEs59zTXu7s", 
        "url" => "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlDAgZO2ZDM
  ");
  function shuffle_assoc_array(&$array) {
  if (!is_array($array)) return $array;
  $keys = array_keys($array);
  shuffle($keys);
  $random = array();
  foreach ($keys as $key)
    $random[$key] = $array[$key];
  $array = $random;   return TRUE;
  }
   shuffle_assoc_array($assoc_array);
```

How can i pass this youtube url randomly to the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ima told, you must have to cahnge your array format and than try with below code.

```
<?php
   $assoc_array = array( "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7XdOyZIkko", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMH0bHeiRNg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEs59zTXu7s", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlDAgZO2ZDM");

   shuffle($assoc_array);

   for($i=0;$i<count($assoc_array);$i++){
      echo '<div><a class="popup-with-zoom-anim wiplay" id="'.$i.'" href="#small-dialog" data-detail-id ="'.$i.'" data-stream="'.$assoc_array[$i].'">'.$assoc_array[$i].'</a></div>';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

THis array will give you only one value

```
array( 
"url" => "https://www.youtube.com
/watch?v=A7XdOyZIkko", 
"url" => "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMH0bHeiRNg", 
"url" => "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEs59zTXu7s", 
"url" => "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlDAgZO2ZDM
");
```

This is equivalent to

```
array( 
    "url" => "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlDAgZO2ZDM
");
```

Try something like this

```
array( 
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7XdOyZIkko", 
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMH0bHeiRNg", 
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEs59zTXu7s", 
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlDAgZO2ZDM"
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help